# GWT Eclipse not compiling latest code changes

Tags: eclipse, gwt, compilation

Created a new GWT project in Eclipse and used the "Generated Sample code" that it comes with.
Compiled my code fine and I run it in Chrome with no issues.

Now, the second I change anything in the code, the changes are not being reflected on the page.

I clean + recompile the code. I refresh the webpage as well. Nothing.

Please help!

Comment: Please provide more information. There is no need to recompile the project, only rebuild it. Compiling the project is used when you want to package into a war and deploy it on the server. Try debugging the application to see if the breakpoints are reached at your new code and if they do, then something else is wrong. Plus work with firefox as the GWT dev plugin works much better there.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to recompile the code until you deploy it to server, try to run in development mode.  use the option Run as web application or Debug as web application. every time u make changes you have to reload the gwt module so for that stop your project and run again as i said above